# Can editing hosts file cause security risk?

Tags: windows-10, security

One of the software that I am using prompts frequently to upgrade. It gets really annoying sometimes. While I searched for its solution, the trick was to edit the "hosts" file in the location:

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

So, I want to know whether it can cause potential security risk in any possible way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's important to understand what your hosts file does. Your hosts file (whether you're on a PC, Mac, or Linux) is used as a kind of hard override for DNS/host names. That is, instead of doing a normal lookup of a particular host/domain name's IP address, your computer will use the IP that you have defined in the hosts file.

That said, in general, there isn't a risk in changing your hosts file. The real security risks come when you override something like, say, google.com or an online banking site. Then, a site could masquerade as one of those, and potentially trick you into giving information that would normally be safe. For this to happen, you would have to either manually change the hosts file yourself or another existing piece of malware on your PC would without your knowledge.

As long as you know *what* you're doing to your hosts file and *why* you're doing it, there should be no security risk at all.

Comment: I want to add something like this in my host file: 127.0.0.1 example.com. But I don't know what it does. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Sanu_012 That would make your computer resolve example.com out to itself (127.0.0.1 is the loopback IP address). This is safe because any traffic destined for example.com would essentially just get ignored and not sent to any other IP address.

Comment: Okay, that means any address that points to localhost is safe?

Comment: @Sanu_012 Yes, I think that's a safe thing to say, as it will only get sent back to your own computer and not somebody else's.

Comment: Okay, thank you a ton.